# Считать аудио в буфер

Tags: java, аудио

Доброго времени суток! Как считывать аудио с микрофона в буфер?

Answer (score 3):

Да когда уже люди научатся пользоваться Гуглом?! На первой странице по запросу ***java запись с микрофона*** ссылка на [статью](http://www.solveitproblems.net/2010/04/java-sound-api-java.html) с конкретным примером кода.

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat.Type;

public class JRecorder extends Thread    {

    private TargetDataLine        m_line;
    private AudioFileFormat.Type    m_targetType;
    private AudioInputStream    m_audioInputStream;
    private File            m_outputFile;

    public JRecorder(TargetDataLine m_line, Type m_targetType,  File m_outputFile) {
        this.m_line = m_line;
        this.m_targetType = m_targetType;
        this.m_audioInputStream = new AudioInputStream(m_line);
        this.m_outputFile = m_outputFile;
    }

    public void start()
    {
        m_line.start();

        super.start();
    }

    public void stopRecording()
    {
        m_line.stop();
        m_line.close();
    }


    public void run()
    {
            try
            {
                AudioSystem.write(
                    m_audioInputStream,
                    m_targetType,
                    m_outputFile);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }



    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       File outputFile = new File("c:\\audiorec.wav");

        AudioFormat    audioFormat = new AudioFormat(
            AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
            44100.0F, 16, 2, 4, 44100.0F, false);

        DataLine.Info    info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, audioFormat);
        TargetDataLine    targetDataLine = null;
        try
        {
            targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            targetDataLine.open(audioFormat);
        }
        catch (LineUnavailableException e)
        {
            System.out.println("unable to get a recording line");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        AudioFileFormat.Type    targetType = AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE;

        JRecorder j = new JRecorder(targetDataLine,targetType,outputFile);



        System.out.println("Press ENTER to start the recording.");

        try
        {
            System.in.read();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /* Here, the recording is actually started.
         */
        j.start();
        System.out.println("Recording...");


        System.out.println("Press ENTER to stop the recording.");
        try
        {
            System.in.read();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        j.stopRecording();
        System.out.println("Recording stopped.");
    }

}
```

Comment: есть у меня этот пример - я не могу понять, как считывать в буфер, а не в файл

Comment: Тогда почему бы вам не почитать [документацию][1], в которой чёрным по белому описан метод, пишущий не в файл, а в `OutputStream`?


  [1]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html

Comment: такая проблема - AudioSystem.write() принимает OutputStream, а не нужно получить объект Buffer. что можно придумать?

Comment: Что мешает методу `AudioSystem.write()` передать `ByteArrayOutputStream`, а затем методом `ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()` вытащить из него содержимое и записать в `Buffer`?

Comment: пока главная проблема в том, что Buffer абстрактный класс и не имеет реализации

Comment: А что мешает написать свою реализацию? Тем более, чо размер буфера не изменяется после его создания, его можно реализовать на обычном массиве.